# how to play the tier VIII halloween ships for World of Warships

Tags: world-of-warships

This new update for World of Warships introduced more halloween themed ships then last year but this year there are more ships but i can only play the tier III ships and not the tier VI or VIII ships. Everytime i select one of those ships a message pops up i can't play these tier ships. Please help me explain the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with a division or wait until it becomes operation of the week.

Below is a calendar where you can see when each Halloween op becomes active:

https://forum.worldofwarships.com/calendar/

You can also check:
https://forum.worldofwarships.com/topic/172613-psa-halloween-event/